# Java String import

Tags: java

I have one doubt. When we use `ArrayList` or `HashMap` in Java, we have to import `java.util.ArrayList` or `java.util.HashMap`. But when we use `String`, it doesn't require the `import` statement. Can anyone clarify, why?

Comment: Thanks @Nathan Quirynen.. you mean to say package java.lang is pre-imported in progrm and i need not to import explicitly?????

Comment: I meant you did not need to doubt; I know, not the most useful answer :>

Answer (score 24):

`String` is present in package `java.lang` which is imported by default in all java programs.

Comment: From the documentation: _...automatically imports all of the public types declared in the predefined package java.lang._ Source: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-7.html

Answer (score 12):

Everything in the `java.lang` package is implicitly imported (including String) and you do not need to do so yourself. This is simply a feature of the Java language. ArrayList and HashMap are however in the `java.util` package, which is not implicitly imported.

The package java.lang mostly includes essential features, such a class version of primitives, basic exceptions and the Object class. This being integral to most programs, forcing people to import them is redundant and thus the contents of this package are implicitly imported.

Answer (score 2):

Java compiler imports 3 packages by default. 
`1. The package without name`
`2. The java.lang package(That's why you can declare String, Integer, System classes without import)`
`3. The current package (current file's package)`

That's why you don't need to declare import statement for the `java.lang` package.

Answer (score 2):

I'm bit late here, but just for new reader, According to my understanding

**String** is present in package `java.lang` which is imported by default at class loading time by `rt.jar` which is present at class path. ****Bootstrap Classloader** (Primodial ClassLoader)** is responsible for loading **rt.jar**.

We always include rt.jar in our classpath, otherwise, you don't have access to core java classes e.g. `java.lang.String, java.lang.Thread, java.util.ArrayList` or `java.io.InputStream` etc. and all other classes from Java API.

`rt.jar` will always reside under **$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib** and you can open it by using `WinRAR` or `WinZip` client

[image]

Answer (score 0):

import java.lang.String;

This is an unnecessary import. java.lang classes are always implicitly imported.
This means that you do not have to import them manually (explicitly).