# In Java, Why String is non-primitive data type?

Tags: java, string

In Java, we can directly use `String` to declare a string variable name and specify its value. We do not have to define the string as an array by using new keyword, even though String is non-primitive data type.

Can someone please explain why String is non-primitive datatype?

Comment: honestly this is not really too clear. pleaes clarify what you need

Comment: Are you asking why we can use String without import ?

Possible duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7953987/java-string-import

Comment: @rousseauo I don't see the word import anywhere in that question.

Comment: @Takendarkk He seems unsure if the String is primitive or not because he does not need to import it. (my guess) Maybe he needs to learn that he doesnt need to define an array because String is an Object, imported by default.

Comment: He wants to know why he doesn't _have_ to use new to make a String object. Why can he use literals even though it's not a primitive.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Strings are objects in Java, so why don't we use 'new' to create them?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2009228/strings-are-objects-in-java-so-why-dont-we-use-new-to-create-them)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String str = “This is string literal”;
```

This is a string literal. When you declare a string like this you are actually calling `intern()` method on `String`.

This method references an internal pool of string objects. If there already exists a string value “This is string literal”, then `str` will reference that string and no new `String` object will be created.

```
String str = new String(“this is string created by new operator”);
```

This is a string object. The JVM is forced to create a new `String` reference, even if "this is string created by new operator" already exists in the reference pool.

Comment: Best way to tell is there are having fixed size of bytes called primitives and which are not(string) called as non primitive

Answer (score 33):

String is non-primitive because only class can have methods. Primitive can not. And String need many functions to be called upon while processing like substring, indexof, equals, touppercase. It would not have been possible without making it class.

Also class has made it possible to make strings immutable and final to enhance security and efficiency by allowing pooling.

Comment: Thanks.. I got my required answer.

Answer (score 11):

The [`String`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) Javadoc clearly indicates that `String` is a subclass of `Object`; and further [`String.equals(Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) overrides [`Object.equals(Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29).

[JLS-3.10.5. String Literals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.5) specifies that

> A *string literal* consists of zero or more characters enclosed in double quotes.

Also, [JLS-4.3.3. The Class String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.3.3) adds

> Instances of class String represent sequences of Unicode code points.
>
> A String object has a constant (unchanging) value.
>
> String literals ([§3.10.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.5)) are references to instances of class String.
>
> The string concatenation operator + ([§15.18.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.1)) implicitly creates a new String object when the result is not a compile-time constant expression ([§15.28](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28)).

It's also worth pointing out that arrays are also `Object`(s), and [An Array of Characters is Not a String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.9). Finally, if a `String` wasn't an `Object` it couldn't be `null`.

Answer (score 3):

Yes String is an object in Java. The fact that it can be used *similar* to primitives does not contradict

Please refer - [Strings are objects in Java, so why don't we use 'new' to create them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2009228/strings-are-objects-in-java-so-why-dont-we-use-new-to-create-them)

Answer (score 2):

String creats an Object each time you assign a value in its String Pool.
Where every time if you create a similar object it will look for that and refer, if that value is not there it will again create a new one. Study more on String Pool you will automatically come to know the difference.

Answer (score 1):

String is a Java Object and not a primitive data type. 
String is part of the java.lang package that is imported by default in any java project.

There is no need to define an array of char, just use String.

Possible duplicate: [Java String import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7953987/java-string-import)

Answer (score 1):

String is object, is immutable, that means that you cannot change the object itself, but you can change the reference to the object.

This is how String works

```
String myStr = "test";
```

This as usual, creates a string named "test" and assign it a reference "myStr".

Important point to note here is, while the String object is immutable, its reference variable is not.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confusing 'primitive' and 'literal'. A primitive is a datatype that is not an object. A literal is a  convenient way of describing the bit pattern for a datatype. For instance -1 describes the bit pattern 0xFFFFFFFF for an int,and 'a' describes the unicode code point for a lower case A in 16 bits (0x0061). Literals aren't restricted to describing primitive datatypes. You can describe an array. For instance, `int[] a = {1, 2, 3};`.

A string literal is just a way of describing an immutable array of characters with some methods attached. The literal is syntactic sugar for describing something that would otherwise be very complicated. For example:

```
String s = "ab";
```

Is much simpler than:

```
char[] c = new char[2];
c[0] = 'a';
c[1] = 'b';
String s = new String(c);
```

Answer (score 1):

In Java, String is an object that stores the location to where the actual "value" of where the String is located.

You DO need to use the `new` keyword when making an array of Strings, as you do with making an array of anything else.

`String[] text = new String[4]`

This create's four String **references** that lead the computer to where the text is located at. Also, all Strings default to a value of `null` because until you give them a value to store at a memory address, there is nothing to be stored.

Answer (score 1):

1. String is an array of characters
2. Primitive data types have limitations which fixed data type
3. but in strings size is vary so that is the main reason why the the strings are non primitive
4. String in Java is itself is a class and has its own methods to manipulate and operate over object of String class
5. Strings has its own feature that they are immutable.

Answer (score 0):

Primitive data types are types that don't have a method. Whereas strings have method e.g. toupper, lowercase etc. In intellij you can check is there is a method or not.

this is showing the methods for the (int) which shows no methods(it is primitive
[image: )]

This image is showing the (String) which shows methods (it is not primitive)
[image: This image is showing the (String) which shows methods (it is not primitive)]

Answer (score -1):

Because string is actually a group of character (char) datatype. So it is being derived from char datatype. It have its origin datatype i. E. Char but int float chat etc do not have origin type. They are unique. Which is why string is derived datatype