# Which packages are loaded automatically in Java?

Tags: java

I'm new to Java and I've noticed that I don't have to load Math API to use it - therefore I'm wondering what are other packages that we don't have to import but we can use?

Comment: What do you mean by loading ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything in the `java.lang` package is implicitly imported and you do not need to do so yourself. more details in this [POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7953987/java-string-import)